# OpenShift Maven does not use the correct JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, linux, maven, openshift

I have been spending hours on this script which auto rebuilds and updates my program on openshift. My scripts are as follow:

start hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
# The logic to start up your application should be put in this
# script. The application will work only if it binds to
# $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP:8080
source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH

nohup /bin/bash $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/abot.sh > $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/diy.log &
client_result "Success!"
exit 0
```

stop hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH
PID=`cat $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/abot.pid`
echo PID: $PID
if kill $PID
then
    exit 0
else
    client_result "App already stoped!"
fi
```

abot.sh, the script being "daemonized", that runs all the processes

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
echo $$ > abot.pid
JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
javac -version
while :
do
    if [ ! -d AbotDir ]
    then
        git clone https://github.com/ArsenArsen/ABot.git AbotDir
    else
        cd AbotDir
        git pull
        cd ..
    fi
    cd AbotDir
    echo $JAVA_HOME \| $PATH
    $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac -version
    $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
    mvn -version
    mvn -e -Dmaven.repo.local=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.m2/repository
    cd ..
    $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar AbotDir/target/ABot-jar-with-dependencies.jar -nl -t TOKEN
    echo "" > $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/diy.log
done
```

I have done multiple tests, all of them point to the conclusion that maven is using the Java7 path, even after it being set to Java8. One of such is: 
JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0/;mvn -version;echo $JAVA_HOME
which results in:
[image: valid XHTML]

Comment: I would assume you might have configured a `$HOME/.mavenrc` file or you have a other version of java in your PATH apart from that I would suggest to use a more uptodate version of Maven (3.3.9)...

Comment: I am not able to update Maven, or remove a java version, but will check the mavenrc file. Problem is that I am on OpenShift's PaaS, which does not give me the sudo password, with a reason. @khmarbaise

Comment: I do not have a mavenrc file @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

I will not accept this answer, but here it goes:

You are able to copy maven into its own directory and then edit the start script so it forces the use of Java8. The reason why I wont accept this answer is because it is very hacky and wasteful. For use only if there is no other way. For anyone knowing how to do this, please feel free to answer.